# Single quotes ' not sanitized

Tags: web-application, sql-injection, escape

I'm  trying to find security issues on my friend's site. 
There is an input box for subscription. I can enter my email address:

```
Henry<IMG SRC=# onmouseover="alert('xxs')">@gmail.com
```

After trying different things, I noticed `>` `<` `"` get rejected.

But it accepts `'` `$` `/` `#` `+`

If I put my mail as

Henry`'`sor `$/`man`#`@gmail.com

Server accepts the request.

And show response as `You are successfully subscribed`

It mean my email stored to the database.

Any possibilities for Sql injection? 
Or any other vulnerabilities?
Or Blind injections?

Comment: Does the server change its behaviour when you use single quotes? If no, then there is likely no vulnerability.

Comment: You confuse the terms "sanitised" and "escaped". From the response of the system, you cannot conclude either of those things are/are not happening. All you know is that they are accepted.

Comment: You are right. I only know they are accepted single qoute ' and when I put henry'@gmail.com the server show response like "you are successfully subscribed." So that mean website stored my email. So the site is secure maybe. Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: Hey!! I'm wrong. Input only reject  < and > but it accept / , * , + and '

Comment: Also accept # and $ but all get stoed.

Comment: Just to add, depending on how the webpage is written, if using a GET request the URL can also be susceptible to xss or sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes are allowed by RFC 5322 to allow for people's names that have single quotes (e.g. Peter O'Toole).

Please refer to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816424/are-single-quotes-legal-in-the-name-part-of-an-email-address

Unless the server changes its behaviour when you use a certain character, then there is no reason to assume that there is a vulnerability.